# SEF url not working in joomla

Tags: .htaccess, joomla, joomla-sef-urls

In my joomla project,I have a page which shows a list of stores and on clicking each store, it takes to a detail page and the link to detail page is now as : 
http://www.example.com/component/option,com_location/Itemid,201/lang,en/location,1000/

I need my url to look like 
http://example.com/stores/1000

I have enabled seo urls and mode rewrite in global settings.Is their any thing I can do with sh404SEF component? 
How can I achieve this?I am a beginner in Joomla.Please advice

Comment: This sounds like an extension not core Joomla. Are the urls on core components working as expected?

Answer (score 0):

Probably this component doesn´t have sef urls through filter/search page.

Try to create hidden menu link to one of the stores (with proper alias) and see if redirect goes to sef link.